# Including external js files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying a script using jQuery and Sweetalert, which was working fine until I moved the custom js into separate file, then stopped working, additionally the console shows that although I have loaded everything in the head tag, only jquery shows up there, the other two files show as being in the body tag ?

```
<head>
    <title>Inserting, copying and removing elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <!-- include jQuery-->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    //Include sweetalert//
    <script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include custom js -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comment syntax is wrong for the second comment, which results in writing pure text inside your `<head>` tag, putting the rest of your `<head>` into the body.

Simply edit your second comment like the others :

```
<head>
  <title>Inserting, copying and removing elements</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  <!-- include jQuery-->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- include sweetalert-->
  <script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  <!-- include custom js -->
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Hi, I already noticed that and changed it, it still doesn't change anything atm. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle link with your complete code? As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong here.

Comment: You are right, there was an error in one of the functions which stopped it, I fixed that and its working, however the two other scripts still show in the body in Chrome console which is a bit baffling! Thanks

Comment: Hi its working now, there was an error in one of the functions ! Thanks